# Question on the archimedean property

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, real-numbers

Let $a,b \in \Bbb ℝ$. Suppose that $a>0$. Prove that there is some $n\in \Bbb N$ such that  $b\in[-na, na]$.
I understand how the Archimedean Property can be used to prove this statement if $b$ is a positive real number, but can this statement be proved with the Archimedean Property if $b$ is instead a negative real number?

Answer (score 1):

If $b<0 $ then $-b>0$ then $na> -b$ hence $(-n) a < b.$

Comment: Thanks, I guess that this was a lot simpler than I made it out to be.